# What's the difference between "Chain of responsibility" and "Specification" patterns?

Tags: design-patterns

1. Chain of Responsibility
2. Specification

My question is:

What exactly is the difference between those patterns?

Comment: Would be great if you could elaborate a little more about what you think they have in common and makes them so hard to distinguish.

Answer (score 0):

The chain of responsability is a behavioral pattern which provides a mechanism for implementing a feature through a chain. In this chain, each node has a precise responsability and can decide to handle the request completely, partially or to pass it to the next node of the chain.

An implementation might look as the following:

```
    public interface IHandler<T>
    {
        void Handle(T request);
    }

    public abstract class HandlerBase<T>: IHandler<T>
    {
        protected IHandler<T> Next {get; private set; }
        public HandlerBase(IHandler<T> next)
        {
          Next = next;
        }
        public abstract void Handle(T request);
    }

    public class PositiveNumbersHandler: HandlerBase<int>
    {
       public PositiveNumbersHandler(IHandler<int> next): base(next) {}
       public override void Handle(int request)
       {
           if (request > 0)
           {
              Console.WriteLine(request + " is positive");
           } else {
              Next.Handle(request);
           }
       }

    }

    public class NegativeNumbersHandler: HandlerBase<int>
    {
       public NegativeNumbersHandler(IHandler<int> next): base(next) {}
       public override void Handle(int request)
       {
           if (request < 0)
           {
              Console.WriteLine(request + " is negative");
           } 
       }

    }

    public class Program {
      public static void Main(string[] args)
      {
         var chain = new PositiveNumbersHandler(new NegativeNumbersHandler(null));
         var request = new Random().Next(-10,10);
         chain.Handle(request);
      }
    }
```

The specification pattern, instead, is a pattern of the Domain Driven Design world and is used to create classes which describe a "Specification" of the domain for which the software is being developed. A "Specification" is a property of an entity which may be held or not. Think of a Flight booking system and that you need to display all the flights which are leaving today. If you decide to apply the Specification pattern the software will look like this:

```
    public class Flight
    {
       public DateTime LeavingDateAndTime {get;set;}
       //more properties
    }

    public class FlightsRepository {
        private readonly List<Flight> _flights = new List<Flight>();
        public void AddFlight(Flight flight) {
            _flights.Add(flight);
        }
        public List<Flight> GetFlightsBySpecification(ISpecification specification)
        {
            return _flights.Where(flight => specification.IsTrueForFlight(flight)).ToList();
        }
        
    }

    public interface ISpecification {
        bool IsTrueForFlight(Flight flight);    
    }

    public class FlightsLeavingTodaySpecification: ISpecification {
        public bool IsTrueForFlight(Flight flight)
        {
            return flight.LeavingDateAndTime == DateTime.Today;
        }
    }

    public class Program {
      public static void Main(string[] args)
      {
         var flightsRepository = new FlightsRepository();
         flightsRepository.AddFlight(new Flight { LeavingDateTime = DateTime.Today });
         flightsRepository.AddFlight(new Flight { LeavingDateTime = DateTime.Today.AddHours(24) });
         flightsRepository.GetFlightsBySpecification(new FlightsLeavingTodaySpecification()); // will return only the flight leaving today
          
      }
    }
```